# AngularJS + Jasmine + handle of promises

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, q

Im using **angularjs 1.4** and **jasmine 2.4**.

Im trying to **test a function and I want to make it return a promise**, so another layer above it can deal possible values.

My issue is that **the function first validate the inputs**. If they are **not the right ones I want to return a rejected promise**. **Otherwise** it will **do whatever it has to do and resolve the promise**.

Here is part of the function from the **emailSvc** in question:

```
// Function found in the emailSvc
    this.sendEmail = function sendEmail(apiKey, token, email_type)
    {

      // Prerequisite to send email
      if(!apiKey) {
        return $q.when("apiKey not present.");
      }

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      // Ajax call
      serviceApiEmail.send(apiKey, token, email_type)
          .then(function(data){
              deferred.resolve(data);
          })
          .catch(function(e){
              deferred.reject(e);
          })

      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

And my test case is like follow:

```
        it('should reject sending email if apiKey is not present', function(){

          var rejectEmail;

          var apiKey,
              verifyToken = acceptedVerifyToken,
              emailType = const_EMAIL_TYPE.SIGNUP;

          i_emailSvc.sendEmail(apiKey, verifyToken, emailType)
            .then(function(){

              // It should not come here
              rejectEmail = false;

            }).catch(function(){

              rejectEmail = true;

            });

            // It comes here without executing any success or fail promise handlers                
             expect(rejectEmail).toBe(true);
        });
```

The issue is that **when rejecting the promise the catch is never executed**. I believe this is with a misconception I have with promises.

Any ideas **why the catch and then are not working in here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are resolving the promise if the `apiKey` is not present when using `$q.when()`. This would indicate a successfully completed promise. To indicate failure you should use `$q.reject` i.e.

```
if(!apiKey) {
    return $q.reject("apiKey not present.");
}
```

Additionally for the `then` or `catch` callbacks to be executed in your test you would usually need to trigger a digest cycle. The usual way of doing this is tests is to get a reference to the `$rootScope` and call `$rootScope.$digest()`.

Comment: You were right. I was missing to trigger a $digest cycle. This has happened because I have been using $httpBackend and the flush function without issues. Now im realizing that the flush function probably is actually triggering a $digest cycle to resolve the promises with whatever we put into the respond(200, "ok"). Thanks man! Now things make sense.

Comment: right, that's why I asked if you were sure you reached it. And $q.reject() is not needed, that's what the deferred is already doing..

Comment: @Maarten, the deferred is rejecting the promise when `serviceEmailApi.send` is rejected. However, I read the test as testing the guard clause (falsey `apiKey`), which in the question calls `$q.when`, which would result in a resolved promise.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mocking the serviceApiEmail.send method? Are you reaching the then at all? I'd check for something else then rejectEmail boolean because with Javascript your test is going to be false even if the 'then' part is not reached, so you aren't maybe even reaching the promise resolve part

Comment: it was because of the missing digest cycle. Kiitos